# jquery trying to achieve mouse direction & angle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to do a mouse direction + angle script just like the game "Pixel". I want to be able to move the element around with my mousemove event and have the element feel the direction and point its tip towards it. I cant seem to understand how the method works, I tried several different approaches to figure out the direction of the mouse movement to an angle but none worked. Here is an example of the game, of course its in flash but the method should be possible in jquery. http://www.agame.com/game/pixel.html

if anyone every came across a jfiddle for this or knows a good approach let me know.

EDIT*

I tried this below and it almost works but only when the direction of the mouse is moved left and right. Up and down seems to be in-versed and flipped

```
var follow = $(".you");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
xp += (mouseX - xp) / 5;
yp += (mouseY - yp) / 5;
follow.css({left:xp, top:yp});

}, 15);
var lastx = 0;
var lasty = 0;
var img = $('.you');
var offset = img.offset();
function mouse(evt){

var mouse_x = evt.pageX; var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
    var degree=getDirection(lastx,lasty,mouse_x,mouse_y);
     lastx=mouse_x;
     lasty=mouse_y;
   img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
   }
   $(".field").mousemove(mouse);


 function getDirection(x1, y1, x2, y2,ns)
{
var dx = x2 - x1;
var dy = y2 - y1;
return (Math.atan2(dx,  dy) / Math.PI * 180);
}
```

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position  Everything you need to know.

Comment: @brad I can track the position thats not the problem. Im trying to find its direction of movement so that I can set its image angle.

Comment: @brad, Not everything they need to know. They are asking for the mouse direction which they link mentions nothing about.

Comment: @Ashe Burlaczenko I tried a method where the image would rotate on its axis as the mouse moves but it became choppy and incorrect, I also tried a method where movements were recorded then analyzed on which way new ones were going compared to last entries but I couldn't get an angle from that.

Comment: http://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/math/trig.htm  How is this not clear?  If your movement is choppy, then don't simply take from one sample to the next.  Use the last 10 or 30, or whatever seems correct, just as your example site does.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you could find the direction of travel

```
function getDirection(x1, y1, x2, y2)
{
    var dx = x2 - x1;
    var dy = y2 - y1;

    return Math.atan2(dx,  dy) / Math.PI * 180;​
}
```

I'm not quite sure how you're drawing the image so can't help you implement it.

Comment: Im using a div and its backround image. Through $(document).mousemove I get the position and set the imgdiv's top/left to the documents.mousex,mousey. So how can I use your method? the 2 sets of points confused me.

Comment: I don't know how you would rotate a div. A better solution may be to use html5 and draw on a canvas. In the example, x1 and y1 is a past mouse point, x2 and y2 is the current position.

Comment: Okay I just tried your function and it seems to be working with left and right direction but up and down seems to be inversed. I edited my main post with the current code.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your comment, you say you use top/left, but that is clearly insufficient: it will move your image, but do nothing to the angle.

You'll have to use CSS style `transform: rotate(45deg)`.  Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp).  Unfortunately, `transform` being relatively new, you'll actually have to add a CSS line for each browser type: `-ms-transform: rotate(45deg)`, `-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg)`, etc.  You can also use `rad` instead of degrees, which is what `Math.atan` returns.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610171/transform-in-jquery) too, where they suggest a rotation plug-in that simplifies things.