# How to extract a rational number between a parenthesis and letters using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract the degree rate from the CSS transform property,

```
transform = "rotate(33.8753deg) translateZ(0px)"
```

with a regular expression. So far I've succeeded to get almost the exact number:

```
const re = new RegExp('.*rotate( *(.*?) *deg).*', 'm');
let degRate = transform.match(re);
```

Output: An array which the third element is:

```
"(33.8753"
```

1. How can I get only the number without the parenthesis?
2. How can I get only the number? (not in an array)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592384/how-to-retrieve-the-angle-in-css3-rotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RegEx `\(([^(]*)deg\)` and get the first group with `.match(...)[1]`

- `\(` matches the first `(`
- `([^(]*)` captures anything but `(` 0 or more times
- `deg\)` matches `deg)` literally.

```js
let str = "rotate(33.8753deg) translateZ(0px)";
let deg = str.match(/\(([^(]*)deg\)/)[1];
console.log(deg);
```

Comment: this will work with the actual string but am pretty sure he want to use it with real style and it won't work as we will get the matrix transformation

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't really follow you, can you elaborate please?

Comment: actually we are considering a simple string to get the value of degree ... but am sure at the end we will read the transform property of an element and he *maybe* think that we will get the same string but not we will get the matrix transformation

Answer (score 1):

Simpler extraction:

```js
let str = "rotate(33.8753deg) translateZ(0px)";
let deg = parseFloat(str.replace(/^.*rotate\(/,""));
console.log(deg);
```

Comment: this will work with the actual string but am pretty sure he want to use it with real style and it won't work as we will get the matrix transformation