# jquery change transform(rotateY)

Tags: jquery

```
$("#div").css("transform", "rotateY("+ '+='+90 +"deg)");
```

I want to increase `rotateY`, but my syntax is bad, is it possible to fix it?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. Do you want to rotate it 90 degrees further than it's already been rotated?

Comment: Why are you trying to concantenate when its just a string with no variables

Comment: [This question might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610171/transform-in-jquery)

Comment: No, its not helpful, I dont want another plugin or whatever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easiest to hold the current rotation in a variable and just increase it's value without having to retrieve the current rotation:

```
rotation += 90;
$("#div").css("transform", "rotateY("+rotation+"deg)");
```

Otherwise you will need to parse the css value for transform since it is string.